# Knockout dynamic foreach binding not working

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm new to knockout. I made two divs one visible and one not, I want to show the hidden div when clicking a link on the visible div and then bind an observable array to a unordered list inside the hidden div and show the hidden div with the dynamic values in it.
HTML:

```
<div class="visiblediv">
    <ul>
        <li><a data-bind="click: showMenuInfos" href="#">MES INFOS</a>

        </li>
        <li><a data-bind="click: showMenuInter" href="#">DEMANDE</a>

        </li>
        <li><a data-bind="click: showMenuOffres" href="#">OFFRES</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="hiddendiv" data-bind="visible: subMenuVisible">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: subMenuItems">
        <li data-bind="text: item"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function MenuFunctionVM() {
    self = this;
    self.subMenuVisible = ko.observable(false),
    self.subMenuItems = [],
    self.showMenuInfos = function () {
        this.subMenuVisible(!this.subMenuVisible());
        alert("clicked");
        this.subMenuItems = menuInfos;
    },
    self.showMenuInter = function () {
        this.subMenuVisible(!this.subMenuVisible());
        this.subMenuItems = menuInter;
    },
    self.showMenuOffres = function () {
        this.subMenuVisible(!this.subMenuVisible());
        this.subMenuItems = menuOffres;
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new MenuFunctionVM());
```

Please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach.  It will get you about 75% there, you'll need to add the logic to get the behavior you're looking for.  Check out the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pentadoc/egtbm539/) for a working demo

```js
function MenuFunctionVM() {
        self = this;
        self.menuItems = [
            {
                name: "MES INFOS",
                items: ["item0", "item1", "item2"]
            },
            {
                name: "DEMANDE",
                items: ["item3", "item4", "item5"]
            },
            {
                name: "OFFRES",
                items: ["item6", "item7", "item8"]
            }
        ];
        self.subMenuVisible = ko.observable(false)
        self.subMenuItems = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.showMenu = function (data) {
            
            self.subMenuVisible(!self.subMenuVisible());
            alert("clicked");
            self.subMenuItems(data.items);
        }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new MenuFunctionVM());
```

```html
<div class="visiblediv">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: menuItems">
        <li>
            <a data-bind='click: $parent.showMenu,text: $data.name' href='#'></a>        
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class='hiddendiv' data-bind='visible: subMenuVisible'>
    <ul data-bind='foreach: subMenuItems'>
        <li data-bind='text: $data'></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```